# show image on both side on accordion

Tags: html, css, accordion

I have accordion as below.

```
<div class="question">Header 1</div>
<div class="answer">
    text 1            
</div>
<div class="question">Header 2</div>
<div class="answer">
    text 2

</div>
```

CSS I have is

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:12px;
}

.question {  
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: solid blue;
    border-width: thin;
    background-color: #5CB3FF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(images/down_arrow.jpg);
    background-size: 5% 100%;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
}
.question:hover {
    border: solid blue;
    border-width: thin;
    background-color: #736AFF;
}

.answer {  
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.active {
    background-image: url(images/up_arrow.jpg);
    background-size: 5% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

This gives me output as below

```
| image    Header 1             |
| image    Header 2             |
```

What I want is add SAME image on the RIGHT side too, so that output would be

```
| image    Header 1            image |
| image    Header 2            image |
```

Comment: May you add the jquery/javascript code too?

Comment: @GionaF : why you need jquery/ javascript code? this is CSS work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple backgrounds?

```
.question {
    background:url(images/up_arrow.jpg) top left; /* fallback */
    background:url(images/up_arrow.jpg) top left, url(images/up_arrow.jpg) top right;
    background-size: 5% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color: #5CB3FF;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/bAkgu/)**

***Note:*** *You will need to bring `background-color: #5CB3FF;` after background image* because the shorthand `background:` will overwrite any previsious declarations.

Comment: :) you're welcome. More on multiple bgs: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ and very interesting: http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/